# Issues with Firebase web development tutorial in codelabs.com

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am new in Firebase web development and currently using [this website](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/#0) to learn it. The tutorial was straight-forward enough, but there's a few pages I don't get it.

1 . On page [7](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/#7), the tutorial shows how to connect Google auth sign in with a button. I'm familiar with HTML code where every button has it's own onclick event to call a function in javascript. However, in the code, there's no onclick event is triggered and yet the button calls the function. How is this possible?

```
//Button code in index.html
<button hidden id="sign-out" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-color-text--white">
Sign-out
</button> 

//Script to call the function in main.js
function signIn() {
    var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider);
}
```

2. On page [8](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/#8), I didn't managed to get the output displayed in that page. I copied and paste the code to my main.js and yet nothing happened. I'm not sure how to debug this.

Can anyone advise me on how to continue this? Thank you.

Comment: Answer to #1 below. It is hard to answer #2 without seeing exactly what you've done. If you think there's a bug in the codelab, you can report that as an issue on the Github repo. If you're asking for help here, it's most likely that someone can help if you follow the guidance in [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question: when you started the codelab, you created a copy of the starter project. That project contains a [default implementation of `signIn`](https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat-web/blob/master/web-start/public/scripts/main.js#L18-L22):

```
// Signs-in Friendly Chat.
function signIn() {
  alert('TODO: Implement Google Sign-In');
  // TODO 1: Sign in Firebase with credential from the Google user.
}
```

You then implement this method in step 7, so that it becomes:

```
// Signs-in Friendly Chat.
function signIn() {
  // Sign in Firebase using popup auth and Google as the identity provider.
  var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider);
}
```

This `signIn` method you implement is already hooked up to the button in the HTML in the starter project, with [this code](https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat-web/blob/master/web-start/public/scripts/main.js#L303) near the bottom of `main.js`:

```
signInButtonElement.addEventListener('click', signIn);
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! For #2, I most likely will try again from the start. Maybe I made a typo somewhere earlier.

Comment: It was a typo. Thank you very much for your explanations.